# Display a Twitter feed from a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, omniauth, railscasts

I have been able to have a user sign in with Twitter via OmniAuth (I followed Railscast #235-6 and made a simple application). Now I am trying to display the Twitter feed of the logged in user. Can anyone tell me how this is done? How do I initialize Twitter? How do I pass in the username and password of the logged in user? I am new to Rails so it would be helpful if I knew exactly where to put the code. Thanks

Comment: May be this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665213/best-way-to-display-a-twitter-feed-with-history-on-a-rails-site helps.

Comment: @gayavat I saw that page. It doesn't show any code. What I need is to know exactly what I have to type in to fetch information from the logged in user's Twitter.

Comment: Last comment points to http://www.arctickiwi.com/blog/download-you-twitter-feed-using-ruby-on-rails-with-oauth where code example is present

Comment: @gayavat I'm sorry, I find that really confusing... I'm not trying to store my own Tweets. I'm looking for a condensed version.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, you don't need user credentials to get a Twitter feed if it's public. Look at the 
[Twitter gem](http://twitter.rubyforge.org/). Once you install the gem, all you need to do is:

```
require 'twitter'
Twitter.user_timeline("icambron")
```

Try it out in IRB to get started. Pretty easy, right?

Now, you probably want to use your API key because Twitter limits anonymous requests, and it can be problematic from a shared server. Do that in an [initializer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files):

```
Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY
  config.consumer_secret = YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET
  config.oauth_token = YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN
  config.oauth_token_secret = YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET
end
```

Get the actual values from your Twitter developer page.

Finally, to get really fancy, if you want to scale up, you can make the request on behalf of the user, using the OAuth credentials that you got from OmniAuth (NOT their username and password; you don't have those). That will allow you to make a lot more requests per second, because they're coming from different users. Just initialize Twitter with the `consumer_key` and `consumer_secret` fields set to the stuff you got from the OmniAuth hash (see [here](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Auth-Hash-Schema), look under "credentials" to see how to get them from OmniAuth).

Comment: Thanks. I don't need to get fancy just yet, but I'm kind of left hanging here, because I still don't know how putting that stuff in the initializer leads to fetching the tweets of the logged in user. Could you please show me how to use the example code you gave ( Twitter.user_timeline("logged_in_users_username") ) to do that?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "Just initialize Twitter..."?

Comment: I don't understand your first question -- the initializer just configures the Twitter gem so that you can connect to Twitter as your developer account. The `user_timeline` thing is what you use in your code to get the user's tweets. You know the user's Twitter handle (right?) and you know how to get tweets for a handle, so you put them together and you get the logged-in user's tweets.

Comment: On your second question: if you want to connect to Twitter with different credentials, you'll need to do the `Twitter.configure` stuff separately for each user instead of in a global initializer.

Comment: No, I don't know the user's handle. They are logging in via my app, so they could be anyone. It's not the same stream every time, it's the one that belongs to whoever is logged in. Or maybe I do know it through some omniauth variable? I'm not sure

Comment: Yeah, you get that from omniauth: `auth_hash[:info][:nickname]`. see here for the OmniAuth hash schema: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Auth-Hash-Schema

Comment: It returns nil. This is kind of vague, but can you give me a hint as to where to put it to make it accessible? I have seen it not return nil, but only in my authentications controller create method.

Comment: Are you storing users in your DB? If so, you should give the user a `twitter_handle` field and set it when you create the user in the auth controller. If not (i.e. your users are ephemeral), then stash it on the session, like `session[:twitter_handle] = auth_hash[:info][:nickname]` and retrieve it whenever you need it.

Comment: Yes, I am storing them. I managed to figure out how to get the id, now my hurdle is how to actually fetch Twitter user info if their profile is protected: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186033/twitterunauthorized-error-with-twitter-gem-when-fetching-protected-tweets I thought the code you originally posted about configuring Twitter was supposed to make it possible.

Comment: Ah, you didn't say it was private account. You'll need to use the "fancy" option I outlined, since you need to connect to Twitter with the user's creds.

Comment: I should mention for anyone that comes across this in the future that I moved the Twitter config stuff out of the initializer, into my authentications controller, so it could pull the token & secret (as well as the uid) out of the db for the current user.

Comment: in IRB, I get undefined method user_timeline, anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

class Tweet

```
    BASE_URL = "http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json"
    SCREEN_NAME = "OMGFacts"
    MAX_TWEETS = 10000

    CONSUMER_KEY = "PMiAyrY5cASMnmbd1tg"
    CONSUMER_SECRET = "0TYRYg0hrWBsr1YZrEJvS5txfA9O9aWhkEqcRaVtoA"

    class << self
      def base_url
        BASE_URL
      end

      def screen_name
        SCREEN_NAME
      end

      def url(count = MAX_TWEETS)
        params = {:screen_name => screen_name, :count => count}
        [base_url, params.to_param].join('?')
      end

      def prepare_access_token(oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)
        consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,
          { :site => "http://api.twitter.com",
            :scheme => :header,
          })
        # now create the access token object from passed values
        token_hash = { :oauth_token => oauth_token,
                       :oauth_token_secret => oauth_token_secret,
                       :open_timeout => 500000000
                     }
        access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.from_hash(consumer, token_hash )
        return access_token
      end

      def get(count = MAX_TWEETS)
        count = Preference.get(:2000).to_i
        access_token = prepare_access_token("178394859-cJlRaiQvqVusPAPjqC2Nn7r3Uc7wWsGua7sGHzs","3T8LCZTYXzuPLGzmWX1yRnKs1JFpfJLKemoo59Piyl8")
        response = JSON.parse access_token.request(:get, url).body

        response[0...count]
      end

    end

  end
```