# Display twitter feed of arbitrary user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I am working on a project now where I am trying to display twitter widgets. I have the twitter names for the users, and would like to display their tweets. I am able to display it with my own css etc., but not as a twitter widget.

Is it at all possible to make an actual [twitter widget](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines) for an arbitrary user, or do we need to manually make a new widget in twitter for every user we want? I have been pulling my hair for hours or even days now, but have not been able to figure this out.

I am using Rails and the [twitter gem](http://rdoc.info/gems/twitter).

If I had @twitterapi as a twitter name in my database I would like to be able to display a widget that looks like this, without having to manually make one in my twitter account.

[image: If I had @twitterapi as my user name, I would like to be able to make this]

Is this possible? Should I go with faking the styling and make it from the twitter data I have? Anyone have any good tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Twitter's gem API here: http://sferik.github.io/twitter/

In short, it is possible. You would just have to include Twitter in your app and then call:

```
Twitter.user_timeline("username")
```

Just beware that Twitter limits the amount of anonymous requests. So, it would be better if you set up your Twitter dev account and get your credentials.

Source: [Display a Twitter feed from a Rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169841/display-a-twitter-feed-from-a-rails-app)

Comment: As I understand this gives me the raw data, not the actual widget.

Comment: From what I researched there is no way to make a widget through a gem. I believe the best option you have is just the get the raw data and fake the style which shouldn't be that hard. Good luck!

Comment: I was hoping to actually get the widget to work because then you can follow, retweet etc. But it would be ok to only display the tweets as well. However I do feel like there should be some sort of way of doing this. Why would twitter not allow this?

Answer (score 1):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/359-twitter-integration?view=asciicast

It's outdated but you can use it as a reference.